# two dimensional vector typecasting

Tags: c++, vector, casting, 2d-vector

I guess this question is building on [C++ convert vector<int> to vector<double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399090/c-convert-vectorint-to-vectordouble)

I am trying to cast a two dimensional vector (stored in an object) of type int into a two dimensional vector of type double.  According to the SO link I have provided,

```
std::vector<int> intvec;
std::vector<double> doubvec(intvec.begin(),intvec.end());
```

should typecast the original vector (it does).

So why doesn't the following code work?

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> rotmat(Mesh.matrix.begin(),Mesh.matrix.end());
```

I can do the line below just fine, so I know there isn't anything else wrong.  What am I missing?

```
std::vector<double> dubvec(Mesh.matrix[0].begin(), Mesh.matrix[0].end());
```

Mesh is defined by :

```
class MeshOut
{
public:

MeshOut();



MeshOut(vector < vector < int >>, vector < vector < int >>, int, int, double, int, bool);

vector<vector<int>> matrix;
vector<vector<int>> lv_mat;
int shortNum;
int SourceNum;
double smallestMeshSize;
int factor;
bool Fine;
....
```

I call Meshout Mesh(x,y,z,i,j,k,l); in the code.

Comment: Thanks to Ypnos for the answer to the first question, but this raises another:  Is there any way to do this without a loop?

Comment: Please post exactly what "Mesh.matrix" is declared as.

Comment: To do this without an explicit loop, you can use for_each() with the requisite functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is an implicit conversion rule between the primitive `int` and `double` types, there is non between `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>`.

In fact, there is no relation between those two types from a class hierarchy perspective.

Comment: Ah I see.  Then is there any way to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use a loop and get on with it ;-P

Long answer: you could avoid the loop if you go well out of your way to do so.

The `vector` constructor you're using takes a pair of iterators: as it iterates, it basically populates the `vector` with successive `element_type(*iterator)`s, so the `element_type` need to be constructed from a single dereferenced iterator value.  To construct a `vector<vector<double>>`, the iterators need to yields values from which `vector<double>`s can be *implicitly* constructed.  Per [cppreference vector docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), the potentially useful constructors are:

- `vector(const vector&)`
- `vector(vector&&)`
- `vector(std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& = Allocator())`

Of these, the first two need pre-existing `vector<double>` objects, but the last is a little more interesting.  As your `Mesh` is a user-defined type, and you create an iterator type that when dereferenced produces `std::initializer_list<double>` objects sliced from successive `vector<int>` in `.matrix`, then you could support the `vector<vector<double>>` construction syntax you tried.  The `std::initializer_list<T>`s are then effectively temporaries that may not be able to be optimised away, but the same is true if you copy `std::vector<double>` around after using a single explicit loop.  If you really care about efficiency, profile and compare with having nested loops using `reserve` and `push_back`....