# Converting between vectors

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

I have two classes: `A` and `B`, and an implicit conversion from `A`s to `B`s. I also have a `vector<A>`, and I want to convert it to `vector<B>`. Is it possible to add a conversion that would allow me to implicitly or explicitly convert `vector<A>` to `vector<B>`?

I know I can use the technique [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6399098/871910), but is there some way to enable an implicit conversion between the two? Or an explicit conversion?

Comment: Your link "described here" gives a one line answer to your question.  What don't you like about that answer?

Comment: This one line makes me describe *how* to make the conversion in my code, not simply that I want to make the conversion. It's too verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you shouldn't do that, because `vector<A>` and `vector<B>` have different implementation (especially if vector is a template specialization like `vector<bool>`).

If you do not like copying vector, take a look from other perspective: you need that `vector<A>` will behave `vector<B>`: you need to convert *interfaces* not *implementation*.  Implementing adapter for `vector<A>` with overloaded `operator*` and `operator->` which would act like B is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Indirectly, there is. It might not be what you are looking for,
but you could have your functions be templates that accept 
iterator pairs as argument:

```
void doSomething( const B& );

template<typename Itr>
void foo1( Itr beg, Itr end )
{
    while( beg != end )
        doSomething(*beg++);
}

void foo2()
{
    vector<A> vec;
    foo1( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One class that inherits vector< A > and another class that inherits vector< B > and implement constructor that takes the other class as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for a trick along the line of C#'s  along with C++'s template specialization. Something like this:

```
template<>                                                     // C++ specialization
vector<B>::operator vector<A>(this const vector<A> &vec) const // c# extension method
{
    return vector<C>(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Which would then allow me to simply state:

```
vector<A> va;
vector<B> vb = va;
```

Alas, this is not possible in C++, so I'll just add a global function:

```
vector<B> ConvertToB(const vector<A> &vec);
```

Thanks, everybody.