# C++ 2D vector - Convert int to double

Tags: c++, vector

What is a good way to convert `vector<vector<int>> vint` to `vector<vector<double>>vdouble`?

I know from [C++ convert vector<int> to vector<double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399090/c-convert-vectorint-to-vectordouble) that this can be done for 1-D but I am not too sure how to do it for 2-d case.

Comment: Well, you do it for each of the vectors that are contained in the other one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple solution which uses `emplace_back` and the vector range constructor:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> intvec;
//intvec filled somehow

std::vector<std::vector<double>> doublevec;
doublevec.reserve(intvec.size());
for (auto&& v : intvec) doublevec.emplace_back(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

Comment: Nice hint to use `emplace_back`!

Comment: Curious, why do you prefer `std::begin(v)` over `v.begin()` ?

Comment: @MustafaOzturk because `std::begin` works with a superset of types to the member function version, so I use it everywhere for consistency.

Comment: @TartanLlama that is a pretty good reason, still it hurts my eyes.

Comment: @TartanLlama Why can't we use `auto& v . intvec` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

double castToDouble(int v) {
    return static_cast<double>(v);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> intv;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> doublev;

    std::transform(intv.begin(), intv.end(), std::back_inserter(doublev), [](const std::vector<int> &iv) {
        std::vector<double> dv;
        std::transform(iv.begin(), iv.end(), std::back_inserter(dv), &castToDouble);
        return dv;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice Solution also this is appliable to other numerical type 2d to 2d vector conversion problems with a little tweak in the cast function

Answer (score 0):

The naive solution is to use two loops, one nested inside the other, preferably [range-based `for` loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

You could also use e.g. [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that in turn also calls [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) on the nested vector, which does the actual conversion.

If you use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) remember to [set the size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) of the destination vector, or use e.g. [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is with `std::transform` and the range constructor of `std::vector`. If you're using `back_inserter`, you should `reserve()` some capacity to avoid repeated reallocations.

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84ef0e3d6572792a

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vvi = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vvd;
    vvd.reserve(vvi.size());

    std::transform(begin(vvi), end(vvi), std::back_inserter(vvd),
                   [](const std::vector<int>& vi) {
                       return std::vector<double>(begin(vi), end(vi));
                   });

    // Output the destination container for verification:
    for_each(begin(vvd), end(vvd), [](const std::vector<double>& vd){
        std::copy(begin(vd), end(vd), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << "\n";});
}
```

Comment: You should call `reserve` on all your destination vectors.