# How do I convert a double to int in vector c++?

Tags: c++, casting

I know the cast from the first array.

```
std::vector<int> v_int;
std::vector<float> v_float(v_int.begin(), v_int.end());
```

but how do I convert second array?

```
vector<int> aCol(4);
vector<vector<int>> a(2, aCol);
vector<vector<double>> b(a.begin(), a.end());// ???
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: To copy the contents of a `std::vector<float>`  to a`std::vector<int>`?

Comment: You want `std::vector<int> v_int(v_float.begin(), v_float.end());`? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: vector<int> aCol(4); 
vector< vector<int> > a(2, aCol);
 
vector< vector<double> > b(a.begin(), a.end()); ??????????????

Comment: @윤희동, I still have no idea what you're asking. What do you want to "convert"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399090/c-convert-vectorint-to-vectordouble I think is just a repeat of this question.

Comment: @윤희동, For your edited question ( which had nothing to do with the original), you're trying to construct a `vector<vector<double>>` with a range of  `vector<vector<int>>`s. There's no conversion from `vector<int>` to `vector<double>`.  What did you expect would happen? You may want to look at `std::copy` instead.

Comment: I'm expect type casting.. int -> double but x1, x2, x3, x4,... one array ok, x1 y1, x1 y2, x1, y3, x1 y4 two array not ok.. i want to know two array convert

Comment: Thack you for reading^^

Answer (score 3):

For the compiler `vector<int>` and `vector<double>` are completely unrelated types, not implicitly convertible one to another. What you can do is something like:

```
for(auto&& elem: a)
    b.push_back(std::vector<double>(elem.begin(), elem.end()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<vector<double>> b;
b.reserve(a.size());
for (const auto& elem : a) {
  b.emplace_back(elem.begin(), elem.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your vector-of-vectors construction is not compiling is because

```
vector<vector<double>> b(a.begin(), a.end())
```

is range constructing `b` with iterators whose element type is `vector<int>`. This will attempt to construct `b`'s internal `std::vector<double>`s with `std::vector<int>`s, which is no surprise that it shouldn't compile.

Comparing this to your first example,

```
std::vector<float> v_float(v_int.begin(), v_int.end());
```

is range constructing `v_float` from iterators whose element type is `int`. This works because a conversion from an int to a float is allowed, but not from `std::vector<int>` to `std::vector<double>` (or `std::vector<float>`).

You may want to instead look at looping through each element of `a` and pushing back a vector constructed from `a`'s `begin()` and `end()`